# My Go server fails to start in cloud foundry

Tags: go, yaml, buildpack, cloud-foundry

I have a simple GO server that I am trying to push to cloud foundry on Bosh lite ( Vagrant + Virtual box.)

Here is the source code setup from my go application:

- ~/workspace/src/github.com/me/ ( parent directory)

  -Godeps

  -weight
  weight.go <-- main file.

  manifest.yml

  Procfile

My weight.go is a simple server that listens on 9000.

1) manifest.yml looks like this.

```
applications:
- name: weight
  memory: 128MB
  instances: 1
```

2 ) Procfile looks like this.

```
worker: bin/weight
```

3 ) I use the default buildpack.

4 ) When I push my app with cf push weight -c "./bin/weight;sleep 1d" I get:

```
a-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-03-13T11:02:45.70-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Got staging request for app with id 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
2016-03-13T11:02:46.84-0700 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-03-13T11:02:46.89-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (12K)
2016-03-13T11:02:48.76-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (78M)
2016-03-13T11:02:48.82-0700 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/go-buildpack'...
2016-03-13T11:03:05.66-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
2016-03-13T11:03:05.68-0700 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
2016-03-13T11:03:07.59-0700 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out '26a578c06a62c763205833561fec1c5c6d34deb6'
2016-03-13T11:03:07.61-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.7.3
2016-03-13T11:03:09.81-0700 [STG/0]      OUT https://pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/concourse-binaries/godep/godep-v55-linux-x64.tgz
2016-03-13T11:03:09.88-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Checking Godeps/Godeps.json file.
2016-03-13T11:03:09.92-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Using go1.5.3
2016-03-13T11:03:09.92-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Running: godep go install -tags cloudfoundry .
2016-03-13T11:03:11.19-0700 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (2.0M)
2016-03-13T11:03:25.11-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
2016-03-13T11:03:34.93-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Removing crash for app with id 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
2016-03-13T11:03:34.93-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
2016-03-13T11:03:34.93-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
2016-03-13T11:03:56.81-0700 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7
**2016-03-13T11:03:57.79-0700 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections**
2016-03-13T11:03:57.80-0700 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"16d3795a-8cda-424e-b509-6df11fb32cc7", "version"=>"2eeebbf8-e84e-412a-aeba-2adc0cffea6b", "instance"=>"910eba711c6e414bb7c6324565d0a9af", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457892237}
```

I have tried setting

```
cf set-env weight PORT 9000
```

No success,
Am I doing something funky with the manifest and yaml ?

The weight.go runs locally.

Code :

```
func main (){
    http.HandleFunc("/weight", weightHandler)
    err:=http.ListenAndServe("localhost:"+getPort(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("got an err ")
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Apparently it works ?")
    }
    //fmt.Println("Hi")
    //time.Sleep(1*time.Hour)
}

func getPort() string {
    var port string
    if port = os.Getenv("PORT"); len(port) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Didn't Found it")
        fmt.Println(port)
        port = DEFAULT_PORT
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Gotim")
        fmt.Println(port)
    }
    return port
}
```

I do get the Log for the random PORT CF assigns, still stuck at

```
2016-03-13T16:58:40.90-0700 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid e5d417bd-c38d-4239-aa61-e9ca67fce79a payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e5d417bd-c38d-4239-aa61-e9ca67fce79a", "version"=>"8d7e80b3-69d5-4c83-9d37-1159d5deeba8", "instance"=>"14223d325c204406b87a131c065c16cc", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1457913520}
```

***FIXED IT : The problem was listening on localhost, I didn't specify the IP and I was good to go ***

Comment: I also run it with -c "go run weight.go" and it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you running this locally? You would also typically have your Go package at the root of your repository, not a level deeper.

Comment: I fixed the project structure toe have it build and run, still facing the port problem.

Comment: Just listen on ":" + "PORT", not localhost:PORT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cloud Foundry docs on troubleshooting:

> **Make sure your application code uses the `PORT` environment variable.** Your application may be failing because it is listening on the wrong port. Instead of hard coding the port on which your application listens, use the `PORT` environment variable. [[Source](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html#start)]

From Cloud Foundry docs on environment variables:

> The port on which the application should listen for requests. The Cloud Foundry runtime allocates a port dynamically for each instance of the application, so code that obtains or uses the application port should refer to it via the PORT environment variable. [[Source](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#PORT)]

So rather than your app being hardcoded to listen on port 9000, it should listen on the port specified by the `PORT` environment variable, and can then default to 9000 if that environment variable is not set.

Comment: I have actually changed my Source ( for testing ) to <code> fmt.Println("Hi")
 time.Sleep(1*time.Hour)</code> and it still doesn't work. I also added --no-route to the push command.

Comment: So I figured out the first part where the command was in the bin directory, switched back to listening to the port and it still doesn't work. I am using the PORT env.

Comment: @elithrar just uploaded.